# Hide siblings and parent's siblings until the given id using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to expand the inner div due to space issues on a button click. When the user clicks on a button, I want to hide its siblings and parent's siblings until a specified id. How to do this in javascript using jquery?

Following is an example:

**Dom:**

```
<div id="p">
    <div id="p1-1">
        <div id="c1-1-1">
            <button id="expand"></button>
        </div>
        <div id="c1-1-2">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="p1-2">
        <div id="c1-2-1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="p1-3">
        <div id="c1-3-1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Result Dom:**

```
<div id="p">
    <div id="p1-1">
        <div id="c1-1-1">
            <button id="expand"></button>
        </div>      
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/nextAll

Comment: What do you mean by `until a specified id`?

Comment: sorry.. I would say "p" in the example I gave. so that I should go back until element "p".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the elements you want to keep visible using [parentsUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/), loop through them using [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/), then hide their siblings().

```
$(button).click(function(){
    var elementsToKeep = $(this).parentsUntil('#stop_element_id');
    elementsToKeep.each(function(){
        $(this).siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

Not enough rep to post link to siblings().

Comment: How do I undo this? Meaning, Show every thing back on another click?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly:

```
$("#expand").on("click", function () {
    // Toggle text
    var text = $(this).text() == "Expand" ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
    $(this).text(text);
    // Toggle proximal element state
    $(this).parent().siblings().toggle();
    $(this).parent().parent().siblings().toggle();
});
```

[See this live example](http://jsfiddle.net/4Qw25/2/)

Comment: This doesn't go multiple levels up. this goes only one level up. How to specify a parent that is n-levels up? I know the ID of the top parent.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would *completely* explain the problem you're having in the initial question, rather than give us new information after we've already answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

A 'while-until' loop should do the trick:

```
var str_stop_id = "p",
    $el = $(this).parent();
while ($el.attr('id') !== str_stop_id) {
    $el = $el.siblings().hide().end().parent();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Wc2Pf/

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine:

```
$(button).click(function(){
    var elementsToKeep = $(this).parentsUntil('#stop_element_id');
    elementsToKeep.each(function(){
        $(this).siblings().hide();
    });
});
```